# Coffee on Enter Keypress Repeatedly Sends PUT Request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, coffeescript

I have this coffeescript code that accepts an "Enter" keypress in order to submit a form through ajax

```
$(".text_field.comment").keypress (e) ->
  if e.which is 13    
    $(this).blur()
    form = $(this).closest("form")
    $.ajax
      url: form.attr('action')
      type: "PUT"
      dataType: "json"
      data: form.serialize()
    false
```

What happens here is that it repeatedly sends the request for almost 20 times!!! What must be done to stop repetitive sending of request?

Stupid me! The answer lies in my controller. Before I have this:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def update
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    if @answer.update_attributes(params[:answer])
      redirect_to(@answer,
        :notice => I18n.t('answer.notice'))
    else
      flash[:error] = @answer.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      redirect_to @answer
    end 
  end 
end
```

Then I changed it to this:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def update
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @answer.update_attributes(params[:answer])
        format.json { render :json => @answer }
      else
        format.json { render :json => @answer.errors.full_messages.to_sentence } #output javascript messages
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The reason for the repeated requests is because it's having a circular request of "GET /answers/1"

Answer (score 0):

"The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers keyboard input." -[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

What this means for your case is that you are constantly encountering keyboard input and running that function. I believe what you may have been after was [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

```
$(".text_field.comment").keyup (e) ->
```

Comment: @neilmarion - Which error? You stated that this was submitting repeatedly. Now it should only submit every time a keyup event is registered (once per letter for the most part).

Comment: It still repeatedly sends requests. Tried to output through console.log and but it only prints once. So probably the repeated keypress is already sorted out but there's just something weird on sending the ajax request.